# Why do I get a duplicated curb request?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, curb

I'm creating an application, which has authentication based on external API with login/register methods. I have a simple controller called `RegistrationsController` which fires a request using [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb).

This is the controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    if params[:user][:email].present? && params[:user][:password].present? && params[:user][:phone].present? && params[:user][:login].present?
      # API request
      password = params[:user][:password]
      body = {
        "register" => {
          "password" => password,
          "email" => params[:user][:email],
          "phone" => params[:user][:phone],
          "login" => params[:user][:login]
        }
      }

      c = Curl::Easy.http_post("http://domain.com/register", body.to_json
      ) do |curl|
        curl.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        curl.headers['application'] = 'appname'
        curl.headers['device'] = 'www'
      end

      c.perform
      response_body = JSON.parse(c.body_str)

      throw response_body # This line ALLWAYS gives me 'login taken' error
      return
    else
      @user = User.new(params[:user])
      render action: "new", notice: 'Error'
    end
  end
end
```

(I also have a `views/registrations/new.html.slim` view with a simple form but it's not important right now.)

My routes look like this:

```
match 'users/sign_up' => 'registrations#new', :via => :get, :as => :user_register
match 'users/sign_up' => 'registrations#create', :via => :post, :as => :user_create
```

My application, after I click the "Register" button on the `registrations#new` page, is triggering the Curb request two times. As a result, I'm always getting a 'login taken' error. The user is registered successfully but I'm not getting any result from the first request, just from the second one.

It's somehow caused by Rails and I'm 100% sure about it because it can be seen in the API server logs that the request is triggered twice. Also, I have exactly the same script written in PHP and, in there, the registration works fine.

In my Rails dev console, the request is triggered just one time so it's really strange.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

If anyone struggles with something similar, it was caused by the `c.perform` line. Just remove it and it will work fine.

I should study the docs better in the future.